# sprintf dynamic decimals, memory violation

Tags: c

I am trying to dynamically show a specific number of decimals. I use this :

```
    char graduationText[1024];
    sprintf("%.*f", graduationText, decimalsToShow, graduation);
```

However when the program run I get a memory violation error. So I was wondering if sprintf can manage the "%.*f" or if it an error of me. Thanks

Comment: In other words, [read the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), and follow it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for `sprintf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) reads like:

> `int sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...);`
>
> `sprintf()` [et al.] ... write to the character string
>          *`str`*.

You suffered undefined behavior due to `sprintf` attempting to read uninitialized memory to use as the format string, and attempting to write to a string literal.

However, you should prefer `snprintf` to `sprintf` to help you avoid buffer overflow issues.

```
int r = snprintf(graduationText, 1024, "%.*f", decimalsToShow, graduation);
```